# How do I get an object to rotate on only one axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5 (latest version), and I'm trying to make a conveyor belt type of thing. To do so I want to have cylinders rotate on the z-axis, and only the z-axis. How would I do that?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html and use the forward axis.

Comment: They all rotate, but not the correct way. For clarification I want them to rotate like [this](http://static8.depositphotos.com/1228953/1016/i/950/depositphotos_10160988-Conveyor-Belt..jpg).

Comment: Use their transforms forward direction then

Comment: Just try the different axis until you got the right one. If you are using cylinder from Unity basic object the rotation you want is the y axis transform.Rotate(0f,angle,0f);

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`transform.Rotate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) method to rotate an object around a fixed axis.

The method has various constructors but a simple way to achieve what you want would be using the following depending on the axis you actually want to rotate the object around.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateCylinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    // rotation speed in degrees per second.
    private float rotationSpeed = 1f;

    void Update()
    {

        // Use one of the following depending on the axis you want to rotate the object, this will depend on how your object is transformed.

        // Rotate around X Axis
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Rotate around Y Axis
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Rotate around Z Axis
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was rather hard to rotate `GameObject` **ONLY** in one axis, nothing worked correctly, adding values to another axis, even `RotateAround` or `Rotate`, but...

```
Vector3 v = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(v.x + dx, v.y + dy, v.z + dz);
```

**dx, dy, dz** - how much you want to change value in degrees.